# What's wrong with this background command?

Tags: linux, debian, python, google-cloud

In a Google Cloud Debian VM, I'm running the following command on the Bash shell:

```
python programname.py > output.txt &
```

I want it to pass its stdout to output.txt and run the program in the background. It is instead running the program in the foreground (i.e. I no longer have a flashing cursor on the command line and text will continue to fill the screen as the program outputs).

The Python program being run is training a Tensorflow Keras model. The script was originally a Jupyter notebook but has been converted directly to a .py file.

A commenter suggested that this might be writing to stderr. Would this be expected behaviour given the ampersand at the end of my command?

Ctrl + z only seems to kill the program.

Comment: Why do you think the command is running in the foreground? Is the program writing to stderr? We have no clue what programname.py is doing. Edit your question with details.

Comment: You don't tag a specific shell. This command should run anywhere, but we might want to ask for diagnostics. If Bash: [A] Do you get a prompt back? [B] Does the 'jobs' command say anything? [C] Ctrl-Z never kills -- it suspends a foreground program.

Comment: My apologies, have made those amendments now. Was under the assumption that something must've been obviously wrong in my command so those details wouldn't be needed

Comment: `python programname.py > output.txt 2>&1 &`

Comment: The command suggested by Devolus worked for me - program is now running in the background, printing to output.txt and the jobs command now has it showing up, thank you. What do the numbers represent in this command?